# display another website into div in my website

Tags: php, google-maps, iframe, popup

Am using the following code to show map in a popup window. But map does not show in the popup. It is working properly if i use http://www.w3schools.com instead of http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=USA.. Anybody please help.

```
<?php
    echo "<div id='login-box' class='login-popup'>
            <a href='#' class='close'><img src='binc/close_pop.png' class='btn_close' title='Close Window' alt='Close' /></a><br>

    <iframe src='http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=USA'></iframe></div>";

    <a class='login-window' style='color: #0000FF;font: 14px Helvetica;' href='#login-box'>USA</a>

    ?>
```

incuding the script jquery-1.6.4.js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.login-window').click(function() {

                //Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        $(loginBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please clear your problem? Is it this that you want to use http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=USA and it is not running? And you want to run this one?

Comment: Ys, It is not running. Pop up does not show the page maps.google.co.uk/?q=USA. But if i use any other site url instead of this, that site will appers in the popup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible that google breaks their normal page out of iframes or atleast checks for their existance and denies functionality (although i could not directly find this in the maps.google.com source, but then again.. its a mess :) ).

Maps.google.com itself provides iframe embed source on maps.google.com though (press the 'link' icon (linked chains icon)).

For your specific case the iframe source would be:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=USA&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Verenigde+Staten&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;ll=37.09024,-95.712891&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=USA&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Verenigde+Staten&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;ll=37.09024,-95.712891&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Grotere kaart weergeven</a></small>
```

Give it a try. Maybe this will solve your problem.

( I just noticed the iframe source uses the dutch text "Grotere kaart weergeven", which  means "Display full map". Replace as you see fit )